# Remove Space Gap between toolbar and tablayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a AppBarLayout with TabLayout in a fragment that is into an Activity that has a Toolbar. But between toolbar and TabLayout appears a space, i don't know where it comes from.

[image]

fragment_packs.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="studio.com.archeagemanager.EventosFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="studio.com.archeagemanager.PacksFragment">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabTextColor="#ffffff" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

PacksFragment.java

```
public class PacksFragment extends Fragment {


    public PacksFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_packs, container, false);

        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private String[] tabTitles = new String[]{"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3", "Tab4"};

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabTitles[position];
        }

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new TabFragmentA();
                case 1:
                    return new TabFragmentA();
                case 2:
                    return new TabFragmentA();
                case 3:
                    return new TabFragmentA();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabTitles.length;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your don't need a FrameLayout. Move CoordinatorLayout to the top element

Comment: And the problem exists in the Activity XML, so please add that

Comment: Add: `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"' for the `CoordinatorLayout`...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Thanks a lot! Is only set `fitsSystemWindows="false"`

Comment: okay i am adding it as an answer...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `CoordinatorLayout`

instead of

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

apply

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

Here is a good [Documentation](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec) why and when you should use a `android:fitsSystemWindows`

System windows are the parts of the screen where the system is drawing either non-interactive (in the case of the `status bar`) or interactive (in the case of the `navigation bar`) content.

Most of the time, your app won’t need to draw under the `status bar` or the `navigation bar`, but if you do: you need to make sure interactive elements (like buttons) aren’t hidden underneath them. That’s what the default behavior of the `android:fitsSystemWindows=“true”` attribute gives you: it sets the `padding` of the View to ensure the contents don’t overlay the system windows.

A few things to keep in mind:

1)`fitsSystemWindows` is applied depth first — ordering matters: it’s the first View that consumes the insets that makes a difference

2) Insets are always relative to the full window — insets may be applied even before layout happens, so don’t assume the default behavior knows anything about the position of a View when applying its `padding`

3) Any other `padding` you’ve set is overwritten — you’ll note that `paddingLeft/paddingTop/` etc is ineffective if you are using `android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”` on the same View

Answer (score 0):

When You are using Navigation Drawer, there is *app_bar_main.xml*  where AppBarLayout is already present, so removing both AppBarLayout and Toolbar from *app_bar_main.xml* will solve the problem.

```
     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

in both **app_bar_main.xml**  and **content_main.xml** AppBarLayout and Toolbar present.
removing from one will solve the problem