# How to remove gap between Toolbar and layout underneath

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-toolbar

Tried implementing a toolbar for my layout but a gap keeps appearing underneath it. What is the correct way to eliminated that gap? I believe `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` or `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` but I'm not entirely sure which code needs to be used as I've heard several different solutions. Also I'm not sure where it needs to go.

[image]

**Fragment XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/my_toolbar"/>

    <com.packagename.SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Toolbar XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_2lines"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dualline_text_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip.java**

```
public class SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public interface TabColorizer {
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);
    }

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    private final SlidingTabStrip_Dark mTabStrip;

    public SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip_Dark(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    public void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip.TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    public void addOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip.InternalViewPagerListener());
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip.TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip, false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }

            assert tabTitleView != null;
            tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }

            tabTitleView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
            tabTitleView.setTextSize(14);
        }
    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
            }
            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SlidingTabStrip_Dark.java**

```
public class SlidingTabStrip_Dark extends LinearLayout {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
    private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
    private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
    private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

    private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
    private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

    private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
    private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private float mSelectionOffset;

    private SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
    private final SlidingTabStrip_Dark.SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

    SlidingTabStrip_Dark(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    SlidingTabStrip_Dark(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
        final int themeForegroundColor =  outValue.data;

        int mDefaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
                DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

        mDefaultTabColorizer = new SlidingTabStrip_Dark.SimpleTabColorizer();
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);

        mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
        mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);

        mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
    }

    void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
        mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
        invalidate();
    }

    void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
        mCustomTabColorizer = null;
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
        invalidate();
    }

    void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        final int height = getHeight();
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        final SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
                ? mCustomTabColorizer
                : mDefaultTabColorizer;

        // Thick colored underline below the current selection
        if (childCount > 0) {
            View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
            int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
            int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
            int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

            if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
                int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                if (color != nextColor) {
                    color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
                }

                // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
                View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
                right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
            }

            mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

            canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                    height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
        }

        // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
        canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);
    }

    /**
     * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha} value.
     */
    private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
        return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
    }

    /**
     * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
     *
     * @param ratio of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will give an even blend,
     *              0.0 will return {@code color2}.
     */
    private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
        final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
        float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
        float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
        float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
        return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
    }

    private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip.TabColorizer {
        private int[] mIndicatorColors;

        @Override
        public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
        }

        void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
            mIndicatorColors = colors;
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity java code**

```
public class TBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_withtbar);

        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);

        final String actionBarColor = "#66CCCC";

        Toolbar customToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_2lines);
        setSupportActionBar(customToolbar);
        customToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(actionBarColor));

        //add back arrow to toolbar
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        //Declaring 'title' text view & applying marquee effect to 'title' text view
        TextView mTitle = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        mTitle.setText(getString(R.string.toolbar));
        mTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
        mTitle.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        mTitle.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        mTitle.setSingleLine(true);
        mTitle.setSelected(true);

        //Declaring 'subtitle' text view & applying marquee effect to 'subtitle' text view
        TextView mSubtitle = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_subtitle);
        mSubtitle.setText(getString(R.string.toolbars_are_awesome));
        mSubtitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
        mSubtitle.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        mSubtitle.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        mSubtitle.setSingleLine(true);
        mSubtitle.setSelected(true);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentwithTBar newFragment = new FragmentwithTBar();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment java code**

```
public class FragmentwithTBar extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public FragmentwithTBar() {
        // Required empty constructor
    }

    // Declaring views and variables
    ViewPager pager;
    TBarViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip tabs;
    int Numboftabs = 4;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_with_tbar, container, false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();

        // Creating the ViewPagerAdapter and passing the Fragment Manager, titles for the Tabs and Number of Tabs.
        adapter =  new TBarViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), Numboftabs, getActivity());

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        assert v != null;
        pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assigning the Sliding Tab Layout view
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip) v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(false);

        // Setting Custom color for the scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return Color.parseColor("#000099");
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager for the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the black part? Check in design whether it is a toolbar or layout?

Comment: Background of toolbar or linear layout?

Comment: Post toolbar code.

Comment: Try to change your toolbaar linearlayout height to wrap_content and add an attribute in toolbar : >android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: What is the code for `com.packagename.TabLayout`?

Comment: @BenP. This code represents the tabs: 'Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C', and 'Item D'

Comment: @MacaronLover the precise implementation matters here. First of all, I cannot reproduce your problem if I don't have your tab code. Second of all, when I use the standard `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>` tag I do not see any issues.

Comment: @BenP. The tab code is now within my question

Comment: @MacaronLover we'll also need `SlidingTabStrip_Dark`

Comment: @BenP. Just added that

Comment: @MacaronLover this is getting very annoying. Every time you post code there is more code that I have to request. Your fragment references `TBarViewPagerAdapter` which I do not have the source for. Perhaps you have a github link with your entire project?

Comment: This might help you to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/52824937/4964308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

Delete this line from your layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/my_toolbar"/>
```

### Long answer

I took your layout and put it in my project, along with your `SlidingTab...` classes. My MainActivity.java was quite simple; I just populated the `ViewPager` with an adapter that created a handful of "hello world" fragments.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip tabs = (SlidingTabLayout_DarkTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    private static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new MyFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Item: " + position;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I saw when I ran it:

[image]

That empty space between the actionbar and the tab strip is the `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` included in the layout. Essentially, I have two toolbars: the system actionbar and the `Toolbar` in the layout... but the second one isn't populated.

I assume you're setting your navigation icon, title, and subtitle to the system actionbar. If I add these lines to my `onCreate()`:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Toolbar");
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Toolbars are awesome");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I now see:

[image]

That's exactly what you have in your screenshot. So just delete the `<include>` tag.

Comment: Your posted activity makes no reference to `R.id.tabs` or `R.id.pager`, and it does reference `R.id.detail_container`. Meanwhile, your fragment **does** reference `R.id.tabs` and `R.id.pager`, but does not reference the toolbar in any way. Are you 100% sure that there's not just an extra toolbar in your fragment's layout?

Comment: @MacaronLover but the **Activity** has a toolbar too.