# Avoid passing null as the view root (when inflating custom layout in AlertDialog)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, layout-inflater

Trying to inflate a custom layout for an AlertDialog, but keep getting this waring. I've seen several different solutions to this but don't know which is correct for my scenario. What is the actual correct way of getting rid of this null warning?

> Avoid passing null as the view root (need to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  AlertDialog alertDialog = new 
  AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();

  LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
  View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_customd, null);
  alertDialog.setView(content);

  alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: There is none, AFAIK, other than to use the quick-fix to suppress that Lint warning. While in general the Lint advice is sound, this is one of the cases where I do not think that you have access to the parent container.

Comment: So considering your response, is using `@SuppressLint("InflateParams") View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_customd, null);` a good idea?

Comment: Whether it is a "good idea" is up to you. :-)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Do you have any idea whatsoever how to resolve with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394566/how-to-remove-gap-between-toolbar-and-layout-underneath)? I've spent weeks trying to solve it but have had no luck.

Comment: use View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_customd, parent, false);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_customd, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 10):

You may try to use:

```
View.inflate(context, R.layout.dialog_customd, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase someone still faces this issue like myself, @Dmitry's solution works fine -

```
View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dialog_set_height, null);
```

Below line of code is not required -

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you use viewbinding

the solution is:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.inflatedLayout, binding.root, false) as NativeAdView
```

So you can use `binding.root` as root